# Ignore MYSQL notation

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query

```
select colFoo from table where colFoo = colFoo
```

This technique  supposed to retrieve all records of the table in case you have no condition for the colFoo and you want to get back all colFoo records.

Anyhow! the problem php db adapter is sending a query in this schema :

select colFoo from table where colFoo = "colFoo"
here MYSQL checks for value "colFoo" in colFoo col and will not retrieve any row !!

how can i pass the after equal colFoo with out quotation?

Real life exampel:

```
$creteria =
            array(
                'partnesr_id' => $organization != 'null' ? $organization : 'partner_id',
                'partner_type_id' => $partnerType != 'null' ? $partnerType : 'partner_type_id',
                'country_id' => $country != 'null' ? $country : 'country_id',
                'discipline_id' => $discipline != 'null' ? $discipline : 'discipline_id'
            );
```

Query is like :

```
... WHERE (partnesr_id = 'partner_id') AND (partner_type_id = 'partner_type_id') AND (country_id = 'country_id') AND (discipline_id = 'discipline_id')
```

Comment: Is `select colFoo from table where 1 = 1` helps in your case ?

Comment: Please show us your php Code

Comment: In this case the issue is really with the php code, not with the sql concept.

Comment: `select colFoo from table` with no `where` perhaps???

Comment: let me edit the question

Comment: @Shadow yes it is but we may get rid over it by passing some extra notation to the colname string to let mysql just ignore qutations ,what do you think?

Comment: Ordinarily you troubleshoot this sort of thing by using `echo` to display your constructed query string before you pass it to an api like `mysqli_query()`.   Please [edit] your question to show us what you get when you do that.

Comment: @O.Jones actually it's zend db adapter i pass the $creteria as array in a where param then the final look of the query will look like what i typed in the bottom

Comment: @arulkuma it seems that this is the only way